# Is cross compiler really required?

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel, cross-compiling, osdev

I came across two guides for making a simple kernel in C.

1. http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones
2. https://github.com/arjun024/mkernel

The first one develops a kernel for `i686` architecture, while the second one develops for `i386`.

The main part I'm finding confusing is, we used a cross compiler to compile and link the first one, but didn't use any for second. So if compiling and linking the second one is possible without using a cross compiler, why are we using a cross compiler in the first?

Comment: Not everyone codes to a particular standard. Many don't realize there are possible pitfalls to not using a cross compiler. Most often if there is an issue it may be related to the `libgcc` library. In the past host distributions have applied patches for their environment that may require host environment resources. Using a cross compiler will make sure you won't be generating code that may be tied to the host environment. OSDEV has taken the position they prefer you use a cross compiler so they aren't having to deal with issues that may be related to the host environment.

Comment: The OSDEV Wiki has some information on why they prefer people use a cross compiler: http://wiki.osdev.org/Why_do_I_need_a_Cross_Compiler%3F

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have a clearer idea now! :)

Answer (score 1):

A cross compiler is a compiler used to compile to a different platform or architecture. As said in the comments above, the osdev wiki has a lot of information on it. But in general, you don't need a crosscompiler only if you compile to the same platform as your host machine. If your host is x86_64, and you're making an operating system targeted to x86_64, you don't need a cross compiler. Otherwise, if you're on an x86_64 machine and are compiling for x86 (32 bit) or arm, you do need a cross compiler.

That having said, Michael Petch is completely correct in his comment that using a cross compiler usually is a very safe option, eliminating some problems related to host machines. Though I have never experienced these problems myself, they are valid concerns.